# Pitch Perfect Team building exercise name?

Tags: pitch-perfect

I am looking for the name of the "exercise" from this clip from Pitch Perfect 2

where they jump on the pillow-like thing at 1:20. There has to be a name for it, right? ;)

Comment: You should just link to the clip as playback on other websites is disabled.

Comment: We always called the pillow thing that blob, not sure if that's the real name or not

Answer (score 1):

The inflatable item is called a blob or a water trampoline. The activity is called Blobbing.

Wikipedia has [an article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blobbing) about it.